# OpenShift proxy for outgoing traffic (npm install)

Tags: node.js, proxy, openshift, bitbucket

the following problem. I'm using OpenShift to host a node.js project of mine. I'm sourcing from a private bitbucket repo. I'm behind a proxy. So is the bitbucket.
Once deployed npm install needs to run on the OpenShift-Server.

Now this traffic has to go out through the proxy. Do you have any idea how i configure that in the yaml?

```
spec:
  serviceAccount: builder
  source:
    type: Git
    git:
      uri: >-
        https://repo.url
      ref: master
      httpProxy: http://some.proxy
      httpsProxy: http://some.proxy
    sourceSecret:
      name: mybucket
```

won't work here as it will just try to get the repo through the proxy. Hope I could be able to explain my problem. Would be great if someone had an idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Searched for hours. 5 minutes after asking here found the answer. As described here the yaml above will set the proxy for aquiring the repo. To set the proxy for the script install use the tab "environment" and set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY accordingly.

After that your log will show that it will "npm set proxy" and "npm set http-proxy" to your desired proxy.